# xml to make rounded corners on button is not working

Tags: android, xml, layout

I have many rounded buttons in my app, but some of my buttons dont work with any kind of background, doesnt matter if its rounded corners or changed color. Here is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorAppBackground"
    tools:context=".activities.GameActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="10">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewGameCategory"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            tools:text="Gemälde"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewGameCounter"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            tools:text="9/107"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View style="@style/Divider" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="10">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewGameQuestion"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            tools:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewCardFlip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:paddingStart="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingEnd="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="3.5"
            android:src="@drawable/cover_quizgame" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonGameOptionOne"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_answer_rounded_corners" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonGameOptionTwo"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_answer_rounded_corners" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonGameOptionThree"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_answer_rounded_corners" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonGameOptionFour"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_answer_rounded_corners" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonContinue"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="70dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="70dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_continue_rounded_corners"
                android:text="@string/singlegame_continue" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBarSingleGame"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar_greenprogress"
                android:visibility="gone"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The buttons with ID "buttonGameOption*" have set a background "btn_answer_rounded_corners". In Preview the corners are rounded but when I start the app the buttons still dont have rounded corners. Here the XML file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>
            <layer-list>
                <item android:right="1dp" android:top="1dp" android:bottom="1dp"      android:left="1dp">
                    <shape>
                        <corners android:radius="10dp"></corners>
                        <solid android:color="@color/colorNotAnswered"></solid>
                    </shape>
                </item>
            </layer-list>
        </item>
    </selector>
```

Can someone tell me how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked your code and works without any problems.[image]
Check your activity theming or maybe you do something to your buttons programmatically

Comment: Ok I see, I am going to check my code. Any ideas what could cause this behavior?

Comment: As I mentioned under the screenshot you should check for any programmatically changes you do from the code. You can even try testing on different devices/APIs to ensure that the problem is reproducing everywhere

Comment: I found the error, it had to do something with setting the background programmatically, thank you